# how to use two negative verbs in a sentence

Tags: verbs, negation

I wanna know how we can use two negative verbs in a sentence. I am not talking about double negative sentences like there is not no money and etc. let me express my mind by examples:

> - I want to go (going)
> - I don't want to go (not going)
> - I want not to go (not going)

now what about

> I don't want not to go? (same meaning as I want to go)

for example u want to say

> I don't want not to go but I have to not go there.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.  I've removed your second question, but you may ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

> I will **not try** to **not answer** your question.

As you can see, double negatives can be confusing in any language, which is why it's best not to use them.  However, sometimes these can help express what you are thinking, for example:

> **It's not** that I **don't want** to go, but I have a conflicting appointment.

The double negative here helps emphasize that the decision to "not go" is by *obligation*, not by *choice*.

Side note:  Abbreviations and colloquialisms like "u" for "you", or "wanna" for "want to" are OK for texts or email with your (young) peers.  In general they are inappropriate for more formal communication with adults.

Proper *spelling*, proper *capitalization*, proper *punctuation*, and writing *complete words and sentences* are critical if you want to be taken seriously.  It's a good idea to practice this wherever possible, and only use the more relaxed style with close friends.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can say "**I don't want to not go**" or "**I don't want not to go**".  The first sounds more natural.  In more formal usage, some writers still prefer to avoid so-called "split infinitives" (such as "to not go").

"I don't want to not go" doesn't mean exactly the same thing as "I want to go".  If it did, people wouldn't say it.  Typically, if someone says "I don't want to not go", they are trying to express a particular shade of meaning: perhaps they lack a positive desire to go, but are anxious to avoid being absent.

"I have to not go there" is a bit awkward.  I would normally prefer "I can't go there" or "I must not go there".

So: "I don't want to not go, but I can't go" or "I don't want to not go, but I must not go".

Comment: It's not that I don't want to answer, I just don't have the time.  An example like this would be more natural.